# how connecting to web by utl_http in oracle10gr2?

Tags: oracle, ssl, oracle10g, utl-http

I am using Oracle 10g R2
and facing the problem connecting to web.

```
SQL> select UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://backend.jofotara.gov.jo/core/invoices/',null,'file:E:\ho','Mmarwan2000@') Output from dual;
select UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://backend.jofotara.gov.jo/core/invoices/',null,'file:E:\ho','Mmarwan2000@') Output from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1577
ORA-28750: unknown error
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

By default I setup a wallet by orapki
and still get error.

Please, any help?

Help to connect without errors.